# Laravel session lost when redirection from external website

Tags: php, laravel, session, redirect

I have a problem with my Laravel web application.
For the payments, I redirect my customers to an external URL (Payment provider), and when the customer comes back of it, I get a error

> 302 redirection

in login page because session does not exist anymore... Someone already had this problem ?

Comment: Well, it is not that the session doesn't exist anymore. It exists, but it is likely not in the request triggered by the external provider, therefore laravel is unaware the user is logged in and redirects to login.

Comment: What external provider are you using?

Comment: Could you specify the payment provider and the method where your redirect to the external URL happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the config/session.php :

'same_site' => 'lax'

I just need to setup the param to 'none'.